Comparing a Flight In Turbulent Conditions At Va And Vb
First, let's cover definitions for both airspeeds:

Turbulence penetration airspeed (Vb) is the design speed for maximum gust intensity (i.e. the intersection between the 66 fps gust line and the maximum certified g load of the aircraft).
Maneuvering speed (Va) is defined as the speed at which the aircraft reaches its maximum positive load factor limit at the same time it experiences an aerodynamic stall when flight controls are fully deflected in flight (or when encountering a vertical gust).

After both definitions, shouldn't be more logical to fly in turbulent conditions at Va, since any encountered gust would give you maximum and equal margin from overstressing the airframe and stalling the aircraft?
For example, if turbulence penetration speed (Vb) is greater than Va for your specific aircraft, and you encounter severe turbulence while flying at Vb, that would mean that a potentially hazardous gust of wind would overstress the airframe first and therefore, not provide maximum protection from damaging the aircraft?
On the other hand, if Vb is smaller than Va and assuming the same scenario as described above, you would first stall the aircraft (which again does not provide maximum protection in turbulence)?
Additional: What is the exact difference between Vb and Vra (Rough Air Speed), if any?

Can you give a specific example of an aircraft with a Vb greater (or less) than Va?

Sure. For example, Bombardier Dash 8 Q400 series has Va of 204 kts and Vb of 210 kts. Although the difference is small, Va is never the same as Vb for any transport aircraft as far as I know.

Related: When to slow down to Va for turbulence?.

The requirements for VA and VB can be found in Code of Federal Regulations, more precicely in Title 14, Chapter I, Subchapter C, Part 25, Subpart C, Flight Maneuver and Gust Conditions § 25.335

(c) Design maneuvering speed VA. For VA, the following apply: [sic]
(1) VA may not be less than VS1 √n where—
(i) n  is the limit positive maneuvering load factor at VC; and
(ii) Vs1  is the stalling speed with > flaps retracted.
(2) VA  and VS must be evaluated at the design weight and altitude under consideration.
(3) VA  need not be more than VC or the speed at which the positive CN max curve intersects the positive maneuver load factor line, whichever is less.

...

(d) Design speed for maximum gust intensity, VB.
(1) VB may not be less than



where—
VS1 = the 1-g stalling speed based on CNA max with the flaps retracted at the particular weight under consideration;
Vc = design cruise speed (knots equivalent airspeed);
Uref = the reference gust velocity (feet per second equivalent airspeed) from § 25.341(a)(5)(i);
w = average wing loading (pounds per square foot) at the particular weight under consideration.



ρ = density of air (slugs/ft3);
c = mean geometric chord of the wing (feet);
g = acceleration due to gravity (ft/sec2);
a = slope of the airplane normal force coefficient curve, CNA per radian;
(2) At altitudes where VC is limited by Mach number—
(i) VB may be chosen to provide an optimum margin between low and high speed buffet boundaries; and,
(ii) VB need not be greater than VC.

Now, as you can see the formula for VA is pretty straightforward, whereas the one for VB is more complicated. While I have not tested these formulas, I'm quite certain the simple reason for the  seemingly illogical VA and VB values simply stem from the way they are "regulated".
 sorry for using pictures for formulas, proved too difficult for me to get them here in anynother way
